# CentOS 6 recompile PHP and Freetds

Tags: centos, php5, time, freetds

I got something wrong with the default freetds (v 0.9.2) in my CentOS 6, reading the datetime from sql server is messed up in using mssql (dblib) extension, and it's said recompile php with current freetds would fix datetime problem.

My question is, how to recompile existing php againts the existing freetds without breaking anyting (the other extensions works, the directory settings unchanged, etc)?

I don't care if overwrite the current php or anyting..

I use atomic repository for downgrading php to 5.2.17

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody needs this, I got it solved using Cent 5.9 with Jason repository.